# Golang Mocking Third Party Lib

Tags: go, mocking

Not sure how to mock and test that the `Dispatch` function was called (properly)

third party lib (example)

```golang
package api

type Client struct {
    httpClient *http.Client
}

func NewClient() (*Client, error) {
    client := &Client{
        httpClient: httpClient,
    }
    return client, nil
}

type Jobs struct {
 client *Client
}

func (c *Client) Jobs() *Jobs {
 return &Jobs{client: c}
}

func (j *Jobs) Dispatch(jobID string) error {
    // method to mock 
}
```

Tried wrapping the lib creating my own interface (and generating mocks)

```golang
package mypackage

import api "github.com/example/api"

//go:generate go run github.com/maxbrunsfeld/counterfeiter/v6 -generate

//counterfeiter:generate . Client
type Client interface {
    Jobs() *api.Jobs #type from the third party lib
}
```

```golang
package wrapper

type Wrapper struct {
    client mypackage.Client
}

func NewWrapper(client mypackage.Client) Wrapper {
    return Wrapper{
        client: client,
    }
}

func (w *Wrapper) RunTask(name string) (string, error) {
    return n.client.Jobs().Dispatch(name)
}
```

But the problem still remains, I can't mock the `Jobs` function because the third-party lib returns the pointer to a struct on the `Client`s method.

Has someone faced a similar problem and if so, what would be the "correct" way of going about it  (maybe its way simpler than what I'm trying to do)

Basically trying to run this test

```
func TestRunTask(t *testing.T) {
    client := &fakes.FakeClient{}
    nw := NewWrapper(client)
    nw.RunTask("name")
}
```

and getting the error below which makes sense cause the mocked `func Jobs()` does not return anything nor can I make it return something that will invalidate using the lib.

```bash
=== RUN   TestRunTask
--- FAIL: TestRunTask (0.00s)
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference [recovered]
    panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x2 addr=0x0 pc=0x10094c404]

goroutine 19 [running]:
testing.tRunner.func1.2({0x100a03300, 0x100bdbd90})
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.18.4/libexec/src/testing/testing.go:1389 +0x1c8
testing.tRunner.func1()
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.18.4/libexec/src/testing/testing.go:1392 +0x384
panic({0x100a03300, 0x100bdbd90})
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.18.4/libexec/src/runtime/panic.go:838 +0x204
github.com/hashicorp/nomad/api.(*Jobs).Dispatch(0x0, {0x10094dcb7, 0x4}, 0x0, {0x100c18e48, 0x0, 0x0}, 0x127d15108?)
    /Users/leodias/go/pkg/mod/github.com/hashicorp/nomad/api@v0.0.0-20220919210521-54474a9534ca/jobs.go:441 +0xf4
github.com/1024inc/nomad-tasker/nomad/wrapper.(*NomadWrapper).RunTask(0xe542fbebb5ce?, {0x10094dcb7, 0x4}, 0x632a0f1d?)
    /Users/leodias/workspace/nomad-tasker/nomad/wrapper/wrapper.go:19 +0x74
github.com/1024inc/nomad-tasker/nomad/wrapper.TestRunTask(0x0?)
    /Users/leodias/workspace/nomad-tasker/nomad/wrapper/wrapper_test.go:13 +0x50
testing.tRunner(0x14000107a00, 0x100a49808)
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.18.4/libexec/src/testing/testing.go:1439 +0x110
created by testing.(*T).Run
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.18.4/libexec/src/testing/testing.go:1486 +0x300


Process finished with the exit code 1
```

Comment: What is the error you are having exactly? Could you add it to the question? Your `type Client interface` should only have 1 method, the `Jobs() *Jobs` method only. Because the third party lib `Client struct` only implements that `Jobs()` method and not the `Dispatch()`

Comment: @AndresGardiol for better visibility tried to answer by updating the question 

Comment: Okey, thanks for updating the question. Now I understand it more. About the `&fakes.FakeClient{}` struct, could you add that piece of code too? its important to see how you implement it.

Comment: Its generated, basically this will mock the interface
//go:generate go run github.com/maxbrunsfeld/counterfeiter/v6 -generate
//counterfeiter:generate . Client

Comment: I see, but the problem is in there. It seems like the generated mock file is returning a nil pointer. You could generate the mock by yourself. https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/stretchr/testify/mock I recommend you to do this instead. Try that and tell if you could resolve the problem or not